# AWS Cognito: Do I need other AWS service to write a full functioning signup/signin system?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am planning to write a mobile app with AWS handling the backend work. Like many common apps, mine will support user registration and login. All backend resources should be secure based on the user's role.

After reading AWS Cognito, it handles both Open authentication provider and Developer Authentication provider. This helps to support third party login. The capacity of syncing data is a big plus.

However, I have some questions about Cognito when I try further implementation.

> 1. What are the user credentials stored?
> 2. I need to add more user attributes (eg. email, profile image etc.) when a new user is created. Can Cognito handle this? Or do I need to use storage like S3 to store the entire user profile?
> 3. Does Cognito support email verification for user registration?
> 4. Does Cognito handle 'forgot password' feature?

All advices are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update*: Cognito has since added a new feature that does allow storing credentials. See [Cognito User Pools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html) for more information.

Amazon Cognito does not store credentials. Instead, it allows you to offload the task of securely storing credentials to any OpenID Connect-complaint credential provider such as, but not limited to, Facebook, Google, and Login With Amazon.

If you have a credential provider that is not OpenID Connect compliant, you can [use the Developer Authenticated Identities capability to leverage another authentication system as a credential store](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) (such as your own back-end service). Registration, email verification, and forgot password features would be handled by the Identity Provider: Either an OpenID Connect provider (e.g. Facebook) or your own provider via Developer Authenticated Identities.

Cognito's Sync capability gives you the ability to store profile information or any other information specific to the current user (referred to as "identity" in Cognito). There is a good blog post about [using Cognito Sync to store & synchronize data here](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3GLBC11LK3IYV/Using-Amazon-Cognito-to-Sync-Data).

Comment: thank you @activescott, what if I need to store the profile image? Would Cognito still be capable of doing this?

Comment: Kyle: You can store up to 1MB in each dataset and up to 20MB in each identity (across multiple datasets). So a single base64 image will fit if it is within these limits. A better option might be to store a link/ID for the image and then retrieve it from S3. Out of curiosity, which do you prefer?

Comment: I didn't really know that I can save a base64 encoded image. The only solution in my mind was creating a link/ID to S3. I haven't decided yet. but probably go with option 2. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

There is now Amazon Cognito User Pools (currently in beta), allowing to store user credentials, see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-user-pools-for-amazon-cognito/)