# Integrating Payment Service Provider with AWS Cognito users

Tags: amazon-web-services, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, amazon-cognito

**Background**

I am a front end developer and I am looking for a BaaS that will handle my end users logins, their data and their payments.

I am considering using AWS Cognito because it can offload ([indirectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287078/aws-cognito-do-i-need-other-aws-service-to-write-a-full-functioning-signup-sign)) the whole create user/log in/forgot password process and [grant granular access permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/details/#control) to other AWS services like S3 and DynamoDB (I want to store customers data).

**Problem**

I want to offer a freemium service to my users and for that I want to integrate with Payment Service Provider like Stripe or Amazon Payments. Unfortunately I don't understand how such integration will work conceptually and how it will be done practically.

1. End user will log in to "my website" for which I will use Cognito.
2. End user will pay via Stripe.
3. **Stripe will somehow know what end user is logged to Cognito and Cognito will know that end user made a payment to my account via Stripe.**
4. I will use [Cognito Sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/sync/) to store the payment information in his account and grant him permission - for instance - to upload a specific S3 bucket.

Answer (score 7):

It should be possible with Stripe. One possibility is to create an API that manages the payments with Stripe, wrap it with API Gateway, and then use Cognito to authenticate and access API Gateway.

[API Gateway](http://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/%20%22API%20Gateway) is an AWS service that allows you to monitor, manage, and maintain APIs at large scale. Depending on where you wanted to run this Stripe validation, you could use API Gateway to hit an EC2 instance or Lambda function to do it, or you could use one of those as a proxy to your own back end. Cognito would be used to get credentials to send the request to API Gateway that would then go to the Stripe integration.

Comment: Can you please add more details? I am not sure how API Gateway works and how would it wrap the payment API.

Comment: Added a bit more, does that answer your question? If not, can you specify a bit on what's confusing you?